# How to generate null strings for FsCheck tests

Tags: c#, c#-to-f#, fscheck

Using [FsCheck](https://github.com/fsharp/FsCheck), the F# version of the Haskell QuickCheck test library, to generate tests from [C#](https://github.com/fsharp/FsCheck/blob/master/FsCheck.CSharpExamples/Program.cs), I found that the random string generator does not generate the null string.

```
using FsCheck.Fluent;
Spec.ForAny<string>(s => s != null).QuickCheck(); // always pass
```

Furthermore, there seems not to handle null strings by design, but I have not managed to pin it down [from the documentation](https://github.com/fsharp/FsCheck/blob/master/Docs/Documentation.md). For example, just picking between two strings, one of them null, won't work:

```
var strings = Any.ValueIn<string>(null, "non-null string");
Spec.For(strings, s => true).QuickCheck(); // throws null ref exception
```

And strings seem to be a special case, because it handles custom-made objects such as

```
class Thing {}
```

when mixed with null values:

```
var objects = Any.ValueIn(null, new Thing());
Spec.For(objects, s => true).QuickCheck(); // pass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to dig a bit into this and it appears that you have discovered a bug in FsCheck.

It appears that the problem is in file Arbitrary.fs and is really only string-related. I had to replace this, where they call ToCharArray on the string

```
    static member String() = 
        { new Arbitrary<string>() with
            override x.Generator = Gen.map (fun chars -> new String(List.toArray chars)) generate
            override x.Shrinker s = s.ToCharArray() |> Array.toList |> shrink |> Seq.map (fun chars -> new String(List.toArray chars))
        }
```

with this

```
    static member String() = 
        { new Arbitrary<string>() with
            override x.Generator = Gen.map (fun chars -> new String(List.toArray chars)) generate
            override x.Shrinker s = 
                match s with
                    | null  -> seq {yield null;}
                    | _ -> s.ToCharArray() |> Array.toList |> shrink |> Seq.map (fun chars -> new String(List.toArray chars))
        }
```

You may want to raise this with fscheck developers [here](https://github.com/fsharp/FsCheck/issues) and also check if my fix works well - there is probably a better way to implement it, but it would be simpler for someone, who already knows the code.

Comment: If it is a bug then it might cause trouble if fixed. So they might upgrade it into a "feature".

Comment: @user2046431 I strongly doubt it, as this case will fail for and only for null `string`. And even if they decide to upgrade it to a feature, they may at least want to track it somewhere on their site.

Comment: Agreed that this should go to their issue tracker, and that fixing the shrinker so that it does not choke on nulls wouldn't break anything. I was thinking of the "bug" of not generating nulls by default.

Comment: Why don't you submit a pull request. Certainly the shrinker fix I'd accept. I'm not so sure about generating nulls; FsCheck's primary target historically has been F# and generally nulls aren't much of a problem there.

Comment: Note that in FsCheck 2.x nulls are being generated and shrunk for string correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For FsCheck 1.x, I found a solution which involves modifying the default random string generator:

```
public class MyArbitraries
{
    public static Arbitrary<string> String()
    {
        var nulls = Any.Value<string>(null);
        var nonnulls = Arb.Default.String().Generator;
        return Any.GeneratorIn(nulls, nonnulls).ToArbitrary;
    }
}
```

and then initialise it with:

```
DefaultArbitraries.Add<MyArbitraries>();
```

Then the test in the question fails as intended:

```
Spec.ForAny<string>(s => s != null).QuickCheck() // now fails, which is good
```

This will generate around 50% nulls and 50% random strings, the weights can be adjusted:

```
Spec.ForAny<string>(s => true)
    .Classify(s => s==null, "null")
    .Classify(s => s!=null, "not null")
    .QuickCheck(); // displays percentages
```

However, effectively overriding the default string generator might not be a good idea if the decision of not including the null value by default was intentional and not a bug in the library. And, if it were a bug, it would distort the distributions when fixed.

Comment: I'm not having any luck finding `DefaultArbitraries` where is that guy?

Comment: This answer is only applicable to FsCheck 1.x. In 2.x  you should use `Arb.register` instead. Also, in 2.x nulls are generated for strings.