# How to override string generation for all properties in FsCheck

Tags: f#, fscheck

I have a bunch of types with strings all over the place. I want to write property tests for functions operating on these types, using FsCheck. For all of them, I know that I will never get strings that are null or are non alpha-numeric. 
Ergo I want to restrict value generation for strings accordingly.

I tried this:

```
let charSet= "abc" // simplified for the example
let isValidString (s:string) = null<>s && not (s |> Seq.exists (fun c -> not (charSet |> Seq.contains c)))
let createConfig left right = {LeftLanguageName= left; RightLanguageName= right}
let generateString= Arb.generate<string> |> Gen.filter isValidString
let generateConfig= createConfig <!> generateString <*> generateString 

type Generators =
  static member String() =
    { 
        new Arbitrary<string>() with
            override x.Generator = generateString
    }
  static member LanguageConfiguration()= 
    {
        new Arbitrary<LanguageConfiguration>() with
           override x.Generator = generateConfig
    }

Arb.register<Generators>() |> ignore
```

However, FsCheck keeps generating values like this

```
Falsifiable, after 14 tests (9 shrinks) (StdGen (2144073619,296598634)):
Original:
{LeftLanguageName = " 1c\J
";
 RightLanguageName = "\026z^k";} (At least one control character has been escaped as a char code, e.g. \023)
Shrunk:
{LeftLanguageName = "
";
 RightLanguageName = "";}
```

So obviously I am missing something, but I got no idea what.

I looked at

[How to generate null strings for FsCheck tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225948/how-to-generate-null-strings-for-fscheck-tests)

and

http://blog.nikosbaxevanis.com/2015/09/25/regex-constrained-strings-with-fscheck/

but neither of them tries to override string generation *globally* (within scope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the issue. Using FSCheck 2.14.0, I tried running the following in F# Script file:

```
#r "C:/Temp/nuget/packages/fscheck/lib/net452/FsCheck.dll"
open FsCheck

type LanguageConfiguration = 
  { LeftLanguageName:string; RightLanguageName:string }

let charSet= "abc" // simplified for the example
let isValidString (s:string) = 
  null<>s && not (s |> Seq.exists (fun c -> not (charSet |> Seq.contains c)))
let createConfig left right = {LeftLanguageName= left; RightLanguageName= right}
let generateString= Arb.generate<string> |> Gen.filter isValidString
let generateConfig= createConfig <!> generateString <*> generateString 

type Generators =
  static member String() =
    { new Arbitrary<string>() with
            override x.Generator = generateString }
  static member LanguageConfiguration()= 
    { new Arbitrary<LanguageConfiguration>() with
           override x.Generator = generateConfig }

Arb.register<Generators>() |> ignore

Check.QuickThrowOnFailure (fun (n:LanguageConfiguration) ->
  printfn "%A" n
  true)
```

This runs 100 tests and the output looks like this:

```
{LeftLanguageName = "";
 RightLanguageName = "";}
{LeftLanguageName = "";
 RightLanguageName = "";}
{LeftLanguageName = "";
 RightLanguageName = "";}
{LeftLanguageName = "";
 RightLanguageName = "";}
{LeftLanguageName = "";
 RightLanguageName = "";}
```

This suggests there is another issue with your test generation (maybe just in this simplfied demo), which is that your `Gen.filter isValidString` call basically eliminates all interesting inputs, because they are not valid.

You could fix that by doing the string generation differently - a better approach would be to generate an `int` value as your length and then, in a loop, generate a character from the set of allowed characters and then concatenate those characters (which gives you *only* valid strings).